# Enlaces deshabilitados cuando se generan múltiples

Tags: php, html

Tengo un código que crea una tabla a partir de información desde una base de datos. En cada registro de la tabla hago un `href` que me redirecciona a una página con los datos del registro en cuestión.

Mi problema es que el primer registro me permite redireccionar a la otra página con los datos que corresponden, pero luego en los sucesivos registros de la tabla, todos los enlaces a la otra página se me deshabilitan, a continuación les muestro mi código:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COD_EVEN, NOMBRE, DIRECCION, FECHA FROM evento ORDER BY FECHA DESC");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

    $dueno = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRE FROM padrino WHERE COD_EVEN = '$row[0]' AND DUENO = '1'");
    $due = mysql_fetch_row($dueno);

    $fech = fecha_español($row[3]);     

    echo "<tr> \n";
    echo "<td align='center'><span class='Estilo1'>$nro</span></td> \n";
    echo "<td><span class='Estilo1'>$row[1]</span></td> \n";
    echo "<td><span class='Estilo1'>$due[0]</span></td> \n";
    echo "<td><span class='Estilo1'>$row[2]</span></td> \n";
    echo "<td align='center'><span class='Estilo1'>$fech</span></td> \n";
    echo "<td align='center'><div align='center'><a href='eventos_edita.php?even=$row[0]'><img SRC='../imagen/edita.png' border='0' alt='Editar'></a></div></td> \n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "\n";
    echo "</tr> \n";
    $nro++;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías también compartir el HTML procesado para que podamos ver mejor el problema? Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla).